# stepSize being doubled when set grace in x axis even set autoSkip to false

Tags: chart.js

My use case is like that user can select stepSize and according to that chart is drawn but I noticed that when I set grace to value > 0, stepSize is being doubled in the chart. I have tried to set autoSkip to false. I have checked it in the sandbox (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.2/samples/scale-options/center.html)
Just paste this config inside > scales.x (of course remove the original one)

```
      x: {
        min: -100,
        max: 100,
        grace: 1,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 20,
          autoSkip: false,
        }
      },
```

Expected result: tick period in the chart should be 20 but it is 40 now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpsps.png)

I have tried to set autoSkip to false.